# Creating subfolders in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iam trying to make folder 'trump' with subfolders 'pos','neg'.

```
folders=['pos','neg']
for folds in folders:
   os.makedirs['trump/{}'.format(folds)]
```

Iam getting this error.Can anyone says how to do this?

```
           TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Use `makedirs()` instead of `makedirs[]`

Comment: BTW You can consider using `os.path.join('trump',folds)` to make your code less OS dependent

Comment: Thanks. That was a sily syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a simple syntax error

```
folders=['pos','neg']
for folds in folders:
   os.makedirs(os.join('trump', folds)) # function call with os.join
```

Edit: include [sshashank124](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3337070/sshashank124) suggestion

Comment: Or `os.sep` instead

Comment: Thank you.It worked.Can anyone say y they downvoted this question so that I can improve it next time.Is it bcoz I mentioned trump?